# A button on my page takes me to Google, using pure Javascript, how do I wait for it to load?

Tags: javascript, scripting

I have the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Soemething</h1>
    <button id='btn'>Take me to Google</button>

    <script>

      document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', doStuff);

      function doStuff() {
        window.location.assign("https://www.google.com/");
      }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

How do I wait for Google to load before executing code on google.com such as doing a search?

Thank you

Comment: Not possible without having special permissions on the client's browser, or controlling google yourself

Comment: Your script's sandbox is only the page whether it is executing. Once, you are redirected to google.com, your script will become invalid. Cross-domain scripting is not allowed.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to achieve? If you want to provide an overlay for Google, you might try [UserScripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) or [Web Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions). Otherwise you can try [launching it in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page) but browsers will restrict your ability to access the internals.

Answer (score 0):

Your script's sandbox is only the page whether it is executing. Once, you are redirected to google.com, your script will become invalid.
 Your only option is to get the page via AJAX and run a callback function to execute when the content is loaded.

Comment: That isn't an option -- Google doesn't have a cross-domain policy to permit that.